# Keyboard hides the focused textbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have problems with the SIP (keyboard). It hides the currently focussed textbox. 
I have a form with some numbers of TextBoxes and I change focus by tapping ↲ on the SIP.

[image]

But then the keyboard hides the textbox... 
all my textboxes are in StackPanel and around by

Is this a known problem? Is there a solution?

```
  <ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroller" Grid.Row="1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="Name"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtName" />
                <TextBlock Text="Email"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtEmail"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Phone"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtPhone" />
                <TextBlock Text="Adress"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtAddress" />

            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: By default it should scroll the page to show the textbox. So, there is something that blocks that behavior. Do you have some transformations applied to the page?

Comment: it should but dosn't. Do not have any transformations. Focus change manually

Comment: You can make an empty page, put a textbox to the bottom and you'll see, that it scrolls. Perhaps the issue is caused by some Style (margins?). It's hard to say without xaml code.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `StackPanel` inside a `ScrollViewer`

Answer (score 0):

keep your code inside the <[`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)>. It will not hide then.

Comment: It doesn't help and i see that others has the same problem:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412230/scrollviewer-sip-issue-wp7-5-mango  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707496/scrollviewer-does-not-scroll-up-while-keyboard-is-active